# In Nethack, how exactly do containers stack?

Tags: nethack

I am a wizard, and I just realized that... bags of holding reduce the weight of items in them.  Good to know!  So, my question is *does a bag of holding reduce the weight of items in it if it is inside another container?*

Also, do bags of holding reduce the weight of items which are themselves inside another container inside of a bag of holding?

What exactly are containers vulnerable to?  I have a greased sack inside my bag of holding. Does this afford any extra protection for items inside the sack?  Can anything happen to any container (including boxes and chests) while I cavort about?

Answer (score 5):

There is a page with many more answers on the [wiki](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Container). I will answer the questions I see directly as well.

- There is danger is stacking bags of holding with certain other things.
- The bag of holding is effective when stacked with other containers (but see the first answer. Stacking bags of holding will make you very unhappy).
- What containers are vulnerable to and protect from varies by container. I usually place my bag of holding inside my greased sack, because the greased sack is the only bag that protects against water. According to the wiki all containers protect against: fire, cold, shock, cancellation, being stolen, being identified, and changes is blessed/uncursed/cursed status.
- Only the bag of holding protects fragile items from breakage.
- A few things can happen directly to the bag of holding itself. Some of them only when you are not carrying it. It can be polymorphed or cancelled, both of which destroy its contents. It can be cursed, by certain enemies or a few other effects. This is especially bad for bags of holding because they can then eat items. It is possible other things could damage them, such as fire, but I am not certain.
- To repeat the answer to the primary question. You can stack a bag of holding with other containers, and other containers into a bag of holding, and the bags of holding will remain effective. However you should **never** put any of the following inside a bag of holding (even indirectly): bag of holding, bag of tricks, wand of cancellation.

What "even indirectly" means there is that it is possible to place a bag of holding inside a regular bag, and then place that regular bag inside the bag of holding, however this can still cause **explosions**.

At one point I had a character who organized things inside his bag of holding by placing them in sacks. He then placed the bag of holding in a oilskin sack. It worked fine, as long as you don't count how long it took to find what I needed.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: You can grease your BoH itself to protect the contents from water. (Of course, this won't protect it from being cursed, but I usually don't bother nesting it for that. Then again, I'm usually wielding Magicbane when I'm likely to have curse items cast at me, because I play way too many wizards)